# Combining ReactiveCocoa with non - MVVM / ReactiveCocoa in iOS

Tags: ios, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

Can I use ReactiveCocoa to write my app which includes a sub-project (existing/static library) project that doesn't follow MVVM or Reactive Cocoa in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short: yes

Longer:
There is a lot of libraries wrapping non-reactive code with reactive patterns. I advise you to look at them first : http://cocoapods.org/?q=reactive

In the opposite, using ReactiveCocoa does not impose you to code your app in a full functional-reactive way, there are a lot of bridges (RACCommand, RACSubject, ...)